# SQL Select count multiple columns and sort

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So I'm trying to sort from highest prestiges and then highest experience (xp)

```
public function getRank($user, $skill, $mode) {
    $skill2 = strtolower($skill)."_xp";
    $skill3 = strtolower($skill)."_prestiges";
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT (
                    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM hs_users WHERE mode = :mode AND (
                        $skill3 >= u.$skill3 AND $skill2 >= u.$skill2
                    )
                ) AS rank 
                FROM hs_users u 
                WHERE username = :user AND mode = :mode2 
                LIMIT 1");

    $stmt->bindParam(":user", $user);
    $stmt->bindParam(":mode", $mode);
    $stmt->bindParam(":mode2", $mode);
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt->fetchColumn();
}
```

At the moment I'm getting duplicate rankings, two people are rank 1.

For example 
if someone is prestige 1 and 3,000,000 experience and then someone is prestige 0 and 4,000,000 experience they achieve the same ranking, as to the second person is suppose to be rank 2.

I've been trying ORDER BY but it doesn't seem to be working. I'm not too experienced with SQL queries, if you have any pointers or could help me that'd be great.

Comment: As a side note, I would suggest you to fetch both "ranks" prestige AND experience rank then determine what the real rank is based on those 2

Comment: Okay I think this solution works. I don't have anything to test it on, but should produce desired results

Answer (score 0):

If prestige is the primary ranking attribute:

```
$stmt =  $this->conn->prepare("SELECT id, $skill3, $skill2
              FROM hs_users
              WHERE username = :user 
                  AND mode = :mode
                  ");
$stmt->bindParam(":user",$user);
$stmt->bindParam(":mode",$mode);
if($stmt->execute()){
    $user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);// get the users id, prestige and experience level
}
$higherPrestiges = array();
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT id
                                 FROM hs_users
                                 WHERE $skill3 >= :skill3
                                     AND mode = :mode");
$stmt->bindParam(":skill3",$user[$skill3]);
$stmt->bindParam(":mode",$mode);
if($stmt->execute()){
    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN)){ //get all users that have higher prestige
        $higherPrestiges[$row] = $row;
    }

}
if(count($higherPrestiges) > 0){
    $higherPrestiges_implode = implode(",",$higherPrestiges);
}else{
    $higherPrestiges_implode = "0";
}
$lowerExperiences = array();
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT id 
                                 FROM hs_users
                                 WHERE $skill3 = :skill3
                                     AND $skill2 < :skill2
                                     AND mode = :mode");
$stmt->bindParam(":skill2",$user[$skill2]);
$stmt->bindParam(":skill3",$user[$skill3]);
$stmt->bindParam(":mode",$mode);
if($stmt->execute()){
    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN)){//get users with lower experience with the same prestige
        $lowerExperiences[$row] = $row; 
    }
}

if(count($lowerExperiences) > 0){
    $lowerExperiences_implode = implode(",",$lowerExperiences);
}else{
    $lowerExperiences_implode = "0";
}

$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(id) 
                                 FROM hs_users
                                 WHERE mode = :mode 
                                     AND id IN(".$higherPrestiges_implode.")
                                     AND id NOT IN(".$lowerExperiences_implode.")");
$stmt->bindParam(":mode",$mode);
if($stmt->execute()){
    $rank = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);//get number of users that have higher or equal prestige and exclude the ones with lower experience
}
```

Just replace references to "id" in the queries with the column name for primary keys in your table

I do realize the last 3 queries can be combined with subqueries in the IN clause, but this should make it easier to understand

Comment: This query doesn't work. I tried this just now and it doesn't sort how it's suppose to. The primary should be prestige and then experience. Sort of how ORDER BY DESC works.

Comment: There the logic for it, just fill in the id in your tables and work from there

Comment: For the record, this query never sorted anything. It just fetches the users alleged rank as a single column

Comment: you're a legend. thank you for going back and editing it some more.

Comment: No problem, just tell me if there's something wrong or needs more tweaking